# fluid simulation in blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, fluid-simulation

I am using the current version (2.8) blender.
No matter what I try, fluid stimulation is not working. Initially it would not bake the simulation. Now even though it bakes, there is no output. Domain is still visible and there is no fluid animation.
Have gone through many tutorials but no solution.

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FmkKvXrzben85DPn_cwTA0Y9hQr72OZt/view?usp=sharing][1]

this is a file i have been practicing with.

Comment: I changed your domain to a simple cuboid and it woks fine. It's make no sense to use any other shape, Blender will always use cuboid

Comment: @FFeller this is not the problem, the reason nothing was happening is more subtle in that not all objects were contained within the bounding box of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

First, all your fluid simulation participant objects must be within the bounding box of the domain object.  So any inflow, obstacle, outflow etc. meshes should be encompassed by the domain.

The also seems to be a problem residing with your inflow object.  You must set the *Volume Initialization* to **Shell** or **Both**.  I don't know why this would be the case, but it's the only way I could get it to work with your blend file.

**Update**

I think that this maybe had something to do with your inflow object having it's origin outwith the geometry, can't really be sure.

I strongly advise you to read the [Fluid Simulation documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/introduction.html) as there are a lot of caveats to specific objects.

Here's a final screenshot

[image: Final Screenshot]

And the updated blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this problem manifest after an extended change/rebake test sequence.
Deleting and replacing the domain fixed the problem for me.
The domains before and after were cube-based structures; to facilitate testing, the replacement domain was a basic cube for first test and then sized to fit.

Comment: Fluid domains can be any mesh, but calculations are made on the bounding box of the mesh, the simplest form of this is a box.